# How to make a recursive solution return all possible solutions?

Tags: python, recursion

For this recursive function, when you input a list such as `[2,8,3,2,7,2,2,3,2,1,3,0]`, it will find a path from the first index to the index containing the value 0, but can only move through the list by `index[i]+i` or `index[i]-i` and cannot go past the bounds of the list or go to an index that has already been visited.

So, if you are at `index[0]` which equals 2, you can only move forward in the list by 2. Or, if you are at `index[3]`, you can only move forward or backwards in the list by 2; so you can go to either `index[1]` or `index[5]`.

For the list `[2,8,3,2,7,2,2,3,2,1,3,0]`, I get a solution which is `[0,2,5,7,4,11]`, but there are more solutions such as `[0,2,5,3,1,9,10,7,4,11]`, and I am not sure how to get my function to continue searching for all the other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carry around a second list(of lists) containing all your solutions, eg

```
def findAllPaths(vector, position, solution, all_solutions):
    if position not in solution and position >= 0 and position < len(vector):
        solution = solution + [position] 
        if vector[position] == 0:
            all_solutions.append(solution)
        else:
            stepsize = vector[position]
            findAllPaths(vector, position + stepsize, solution, all_solutions) #step forward
            findAllPaths(vector, position - stepsize, solution, all_solutions) #step back
    return all_solutions

def findPaths(vector):
    paths = findAllPaths(vector, 0, [], [])
    if paths:
        return paths
    else:
        print("No possible path")
        return 0
```

EDIT:

Each recursive call results in a new **stack frame**, which is a block of memory containing the function arguments and any local variables created during that call. Each call in turn makes two recursive calls, each with its own stack frame lying on top of the previous one. This precariously wide tower of stack frames is called a **call stack**, and traces the execution of a recursive function. Eventually, we either go out of bounds or reach the zero in our vector, at which point we return our solution. As you rightly note, the value of `position` in this stack frame is 11. When we hit the return statement, the return value is passed to the previous frame in the stack, and everything else in the current stack frame is discarded. In this way each stack frame, and hence each recursive call, maintains a different value for `position` that does not affect the value of `position` in the function that called it.

So how do we ensure we don't have duplicate solutions? Consider the candidate solutions after each recursive calls. An invocation of `findAllPaths` with a candidate solution of length **n** either terminates (if `vector[position] == 0`) or makes two recursive calls to findAllPaths, each with solutions of length **n + 1**. In this case, the last element of the two respective candidate solutions are`position + vector[position]` or `position - vector[position]`. These are the identical iff `vector[position] == 0]`, in which case we would already have terminated. Hence the two candidate solutions in our recursive calls are distinct, and the length of the candidate solution increases with each recursive call. Combined, these two facts mean we can never have identical paths in a solution.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how the function goes through the list again to find other solutions after the first one? Like after the first solution is found, wouldn't position= 11? How does it start at 0 again and how does it know not to copy the same path as the first solution?

Comment: Edited my answer to try to make things a bit clearer. Please point out anything that's still confusing.

Comment: So when the return statement is hit and the return value is passed to the previous frame, would that mean that position =4 now? Since that was the previous value of position before 11? Also I'm not sure what you mean when you say that each recursive call has a different position value that doesn't affect the value of position in the function. Does that mean that the initial value of position which is 0 will always remain? Sorry for all the questions I'm still relatively new to programming and am finding recursion difficult to understand.

Comment: Exactly, after all the recursive calls are finished and it's time to return the final result, position = 0. I found it helpful to use a simpler vector and work through the algorithm by hand to see what happens to all the variables during the recursive calls.